# How to tell CVXPY that x^T * x is SDP?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

```
    x = cp.Variable((m, n))
```

> x is some rectangular matrix

```
    z = cp.Variable((n, n), PSD=True)
```

> z should be equal to X^T * X which is always PSD

```
    e_1 = cp.Variable()
    e_2 = cp.Variable()
    obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(x - obj_matrix) + omega_k * e_1 + omega_k * e_2)
    constr1 = (e_1 * np.eye(n - rank) - np.transpose(v_k_prev_1) @ z @ v_k_prev_1) >> 0
    aux = (np.eye(m + n, m) @ (np.eye(m, m + n) + x @ np.eye(n, m + n, k=m)) +
           np.eye(m + n, n, k=-m) @ (cp.transpose(x) @ np.eye(m, m + n) +
                                     z @ np.eye(n, m + n, k=m)))
    constr2 = (e_2 * np.eye(n) - np.transpose(v_k_prev_2) @ aux @ v_k_prev_2) >> 0
    constr3 = e_1 <= e_k_prev_1
    constr4 = e_2 <= e_k_prev_2
    constr5 = z == cp.transpose(x) @ x
    prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints=[constr1, constr2, constr3, constr4, constr5])
    prob.solve()
```

> This is an iteration of a low-rank approximation algorithm.
> First I tried it on PSD matrices only, but when I tried to change it to work on rectangular matrices, this error occurred. I guess CVXPY doesn't know that X^T * X is always PSD and I don't know how to code that.

> This is the error that I got
> The following constraints are not DCP: var1 == var0.T @ var0 , because
> the following subexpressions are not: |--  var0.T @ var0 var0.T @ var0
>
> - Promote(-0.0, (10, 10)) >> 0 , because the following subexpressions are not: |--  var0.T @ var0

Comment: A bit hard to read and no context, but i guess you are looking for [quad_form](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.other_atoms.html#quad-form) - ([Table of Functions](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#scalar-functions) )

Comment: Note that any nonlinear equality constraint is non-convex.